# "Nothing" required in call function - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, call

I wrote a method which extracts contents from an external database and insert them into a List. I wrote this method, but it gives me an error on the **call[j]!!.enqueue(object : Callback {**:

```
    private val call = arrayOfNulls<Call<*>?>(NUM_ROWS)

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
        recyclerView[0] = view?.findViewById(R.id.rc_view)
        recyclerView[1] = view?.findViewById(R.id.rc_view2)
        recyclerView[2] = view?.findViewById(R.id.rc_view3)
        loadMovie() 
        return view
    }

    private fun loadMovie() {
        val apiService = getClient(context)!!.create(ApiService::class.java)
        for (j in 0 until NUM_ROWS) {
            call[j] = apiService.getDiscover(BuildConfig.API_KEY, Values.LANGUAGE, Values.SORT_BY[0], Values.ADULT, GENRE.get(0), Values.PAGE[0])
        }
        for (j in 0 until NUM_ROWS) {
            call[j]!!.enqueue(object : Callback<MovieResponse> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<MovieResponse>, response: Response<MovieResponse>) {
                    //TODO
                    }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<MovieResponse>, t: Throwable) {}
            })
        }
    }
```

The error says:

Type mismatch - Required: Nothing

The problem is that if I insert it as Nothing it will return an empty list. How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Call<*>` means it can be a `Call<MovieResponse>`, `Call<Int>` or whatever else; you can't enqueue a `Callback<MovieResponse>` because it may not be a `Call<MovieResponse>`. You should be able simply to change the first line to

```
private val call = arrayOfNulls<Call<MovieResponse>>(NUM_ROWS)
```

(you don't need to specify `?` here because it returns `Array<T?>` anyway.)